# Manipulation on the data from the richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, windows

Am trying to extract a certain line from the String that am getting from the richtextbox. Here is my richbox text that am getting.

```
AZD0495911180U1200811040957
374058860984303
8L589M
08081990
```

I want to move to the third line count its characters and then if the count is 6 then i want to move to the previous line and extract it. the result should be me getting 374058860984303 only. When i get the richboxtext in a string and debug i get the following:

```
AZD0495911180U1200811040957\n374058860984303\n8L589M\n
```

Please help me how can i acheive this:
I have searched about Environment.Newline function but i ain't able to figure out how to use it in this context to move between lines and get the desired data extracted!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this....

```
  var str = "AZD0495911180U1200811040957\n374058860984303\n8L589M\n";
  var strArr = str.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

Now search for your string in the array "strArr" and take the array memeber whatever you want